# HostNameProp and PortProp is no longer present in KafkaConfig class from package kafka.server

Tags: apache-kafka

HostNameProp and PortProp is no longer present in  KafkaConfig class from package kafka.server .
The version of Kafka_2.12 is 3.4.0 .Please help me with alterntive properties

Comment: Please clarify how/where you are using these. `advertised.host` and `advertised.port` have long been deprecated properties

Comment: I am using KafkaConfig.PortProp() and KafkaServer.config.hostName()

Comment: I understand that, but for what purpose? Why can't you use `listeners` config which has replaced both of these? Or as mentioned in your other post, there are other ways to test a broker

Comment: which listeners are u referring?are there any other ways to create an embedded broker?

Comment: See [Broker configs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs). Or the Javadoc. And yes [there are](https://github.com/salesforce/kafka-junit), several different, [ways to test Kafka](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-kafka-testing)

Comment: @OneCricketeer - one use case would be that you are trying to make security upgrades but don't want to make a lot of refactors to the code. I am seeing this same error while trying to address security vulnerabilities without touching a repo that my team does not own.

Comment: @gtee These functions have been deprecated for a while. They were going to be removed eventually, and aren't directly security related